# ts-node doesn't log anything to the console

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

I have a simple node program with an import

```
import { y } from './y';

console.log('Y=');
console.log(y);
```

Doesn't really matter, important is that I have an `import` and a `console.log`. Now when I try to run this code

```
$> ts-node test.ts
import { y } from './y';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
...
```

I get an error. So, without any additional information `ts-node` doesn't understand `import`. So I created the following `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "ES2017",
       "module": "ESNext"
   }
}
```

Now it doesn't throw the import error, but I also don't see any output from the program too.

I get the feeling my tsconfig.json is just wrong, any suggestion what might be the case?

Comment: try "module":"commonJs" as well as "esModuleInterop": true,

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion, but that produces the same result

Comment: what did you do?